# Login page with multiple Html forms in java?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

Can anyone please explain about Login page that contains multiple forms. I mean On submitting some details it should goto some other html page there we have to enter some other details after that it should goto to final html page there other details of the form are entered and finally on submitting that html  all the details are stored in the database? We daily saw so many Sites that contain this type of Login forms .Can you please suggest a one example to explain the problem?

Comment: Read about Servlets, JSP and MVC first..

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean when data is entered by turns one after another or on different pages. And then make single submit. It isn't multiple forms. It's single form. In this case you can **store entered data in [session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)** and perform specific actions with stored data when user submit. In general case immediately storing entered data in database isn't good solution. Because these data aren't important as long as user hasn't made a final submit. And database commit is much more expensive than storing in session.

Multiple forms mean several forms on one page:

```
<form name="firstForm" action="firstAction" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="userName">
   <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>

<form name="secondForm" action="secondAction" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="hiddenParam" value="paramValue">
   <input type="submit" value="Remove">
</form>
```

This can be useful if you wish to process your forms by different handlers or to correlate these with different HTTP methods.

Comment: I got the point . Session and cookies are the best way to store the data of the form for further usage. Thank you  Andrey kapelchik ...